# Why does 'p' print the last variable's value?

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
a=10
b=20
p (a && b)
```

The above `p` statement prints the value of the last variable. Why does it not print the values of both variables?

Comment: see the output of `p a, b`

Comment: FWIW, `p (a || b)` prints the value of `a` :)

Comment: "p statement prints the value of the last variable" - no, it prints the value of the expression you pass it. Value of that expression happens to be equal to `b`.

Comment: What do you think `&&` does?

Answer (score 5):

`a` is truthy, so `a && b` returns `b`. `p` takes that argument, and prints it.

Comment: minor nitpick, the question is about `p` _printing_ stuff, not returning it.

Answer (score 2):

`p (a && b)` does not mean *"print a and b"*.

`&&` is an operator. `a && b` is (almost) equivalent to:

```
unless a
  a
else
  b
end
```

It returns `a` if `a` is either `nil` or `false`:

```
nil && 123   #=> nil
false && 123 #=> false
```

and it returns `b` otherwise:

```
:foo && 123 #=> 123
:bar && 123 #=> 123
```

Your code is evaluated as:

```
a = 10
b = 20
p (a && b)
p (10 && 20)
p (20)
p 20
```

In order to print two values via `p`, you have to pass them as separate arguments:

```
p a, b

# or

p(a, b)
```

The parentheses are optional, but if you use them, there is no space between `p` and `(`.